# Send all actions on self-hosted GitLab to a service

Tags: git, gitlab

Is it possible to send all actions / builds that happen on my self-hosted GitLab instance to a service like Slack or a plain webhook?

This would be a lot easier than setting up a service for every single project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an [enterprise only feature](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/web_hooks/web_hooks.html#webhooks)

> In GitLab Enterprise Edition you can configure web hooks globally for
>   the whole group. You can add the group level web hooks on the group
>   settings page Settings > Webhooks.